# Pool billard ball route function (the angle of reflection is equal to the angle of incidence)

Tags: functions, angle, reflection

Recently I have found an exercise for algorithmics students, in which I have to implement algorithm, which will calculate the ball route after hit and return specific destination pocket or word "None" if there isn't any. Physics occuring in the model is very simple, the angle of reflection is equal to the angle of incidence and there is no friction. Program should read following parameters (integers):

- $s_x, s_y$ - width and height of pool table
- $p_x, p_y$ - start position of ball
- $w_x, w_y$ - vector coordinates

Pockets are single points (as well as the ball) and their positions are:

- GP - (0, height)
- GS - (width/2, height)
- GP - (width, height)
- DL - (0, 0)
- DS - (width/2, 0)
- DP - (width, 0)

Is there any way to calculate function of the ball route and check which of the pockets is contained by this function?

Sample pool billard picture described by parameters $s_x=10, s_y=5, p_x= 7, p_y=4, w_x=1, w_y=2$:

[image]

Comment: How wide are the pockets and what is the radius of the ball ?

Comment: They are single points, I have edited my post and added their coordinates.

Comment: Are you familiar with differential equations?

Comment: Do you require exactly one reflection ?

Comment: @Michał McGovern - I know basics.

Comment: @WW1 - No, Ball can reflect infinite times.

Comment: Tile the plane with an infinite number of copies of the pool table. You will then only need to calculate whether or not a straight line comes within some distance of certain lattice points. Take care to identify which lattice point corresponds which which pocket.